# How to use refer correctly in a sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage

Are the following sentences correct?

> 1. He refers god as his mother.
> 2. He refers to his mother as god.
> 3. He refers his mother as god.

> 4. I refer temple as my school.
> 5. I refer to my school as a temple.
> 6. I refer my school as a temple.

Do the they mean the same or are different? Could you please tell me the differences between 'refer' and 'refer to'.

Comment: It might help to look at "referral".  Say a person wants a job, and we know the person and trust them.  The person might ask us for a referral, and then we would refer the person to the employer - we would give them a referral.

Comment: You could also look up "reference".  These are general, abstract, words, so they have many related meanings.

Comment: 'He refers to God as his mother' and 'He refers to his mother as God' have opposite meanings, and so do (4) and (5) if you add _to_ to (4).

Answer (score 1):

Only sentences 2 and 5 are correct. In this kind of construction we should always use "refer to" not just "refer". When "**refer**" is being used in the sense of "mention" or "talk about" it is always "refer to". Only when  the verb "refer" is used in the sense of "direct" is it used without an mediated "to" after it, and even there a "to" is normally part of the construction. For example:

> I referred him to the employee handbook for the rules on vacation.

> The judge referred her to a higher court for a decision.

Comment: Thank you so much @DavidSiegel for your quick and clear answer.